# MVC Web API Post method with custom action name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

And I wrote custom action names for ever process.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In webapi config I wrote like this and in controller, I started like below

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Control(List<string>codes,string updateperson,string refPeriod, int actualyear, int actualmonth)
{
```

For get methods, everything works well but for post method it doesn't work and gives error like below.

In body in post I send

```
{codes: ["CPM2018-004"], updateperson: "E3852", refPeriod: "SFC18", actualyear: 2018, actualmonth: 12}
```

> Request URL:http://localhost:50941/Api/Investment/Control Request
>   Method:POST Status Code:404 Not Found Remote Address:[::1]:50941
>   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

How can I sreceive post requests to web API with custom action name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create model to hold value being posted.

```
public class ControlViewModel {
    public List<string> codes { get; set; }
    public string updateperson { get; set; }
    public string refPeriod { get; set; }
    public int actualyear { get; set; }
    public int actualmonth { get; set; }
}
```

And then update the action to expect the data in the BODY of the request

```
public class InvestmentController : ApiController {

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Control([FromBody]ControlViewModel data) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)